# android actionbar padding left

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using actionbar in my app and Theme.Holo. I've enabled the back arrow on the actionbar, but it is a little strange, not like a normal arrow and I want there some padding - before the arrow and after.

[image]

```
     final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle(R.string.main_activity_toolbar_title);
```

I don't want to use toolbar or change theme or recreate anything. I just need to add a padding there, programmatically or via style.xml.

I tried to override the Holo theme in style.xml:

```
   <style name="Mytheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dip</item>
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/upandback1</item>
    <item name="app:contentInsetLeft">10dip</item>
    <item name="app:contentInsetStart">10dip</item>

</style>
```

But nothing works. The new arrow is ignored, but I don't care, I just need the padding. The paddingLeft works, but for entire layout, not the actionbar only. And the rest - contentInsetLeft, works not.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write this way:

1.First way

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable._0001_next_icon);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title here");
```

2.Second way

->In your manifest file apply theam Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar for this activity

-> In your layout implement this :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:textAlignment="center">

       <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/back_btn_icon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/buttonTheam"
        android:text="@string/POST_TITLE"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

it will look like this
[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks, in 1st option the setHomeAsUpIndicator call requires API18, and I am supporting min.APi 15, but on my device it works but shows the arrow in the actionbar center. So I will consider the 2nd option.